# How do I install a driver for a Broadcom BCM43142?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers

I need help installing a driver for a Broadcom BCM43142 on 14.04.2.  If I run `lspci` I indeed find the device as:

```
network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 1)
```

But Ubuntu apparently does not come with this driver pre-loaded. I don’t have a clue what command to run to get this, where to get it, and how to install the driver once I *do* get it. I am completely new to Linux.

Comment: In fact, I'm laughing  hysterically. First of all, you need to be connected with a ethernet cable to Internet (wired connection). Then you need to run this: `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and reboot. Then it may work. Hope it helps. **;-)**

Comment: yeah, I have the ethernet cable connected. :) OK, trying that now... so I get the sudo apt-get install... but how did you know the "firmware-b43-installer"... ? Is there a place to get the file or driver name?  Sorry but like I said, newbie blues... Oh God I love feeling incompetent.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was able to run the command.  I still only have a wired connection available.  At this point, my wire better be very long.  It is not recognizing that I have a wireless card at all.

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

it will download and install wl driver. It should work.